# how can I merge SUM and COUNT in select of SQL

Tags: sql, select, count, group-by, sum

I want to merge sum and count in SQL

```
select sum(A),B from TableA
group by B 
having c>3
```

.

```
select Count(A),B from TableA
group by B 
having c>3
```

result of select 1 and select 2 is more than one records
How can I have something like this on one select?

```
sum(A)*count(A)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this?

```
SELECT SUM(A) as [Sum], COUNT(A) as [Count], SUM(A)*COUNT(A) as [Multiply],B
FROM TableA
GROUP BY B
HAVING C > 3
```